# Copy keyframes ending on current frame

Tags: video-sequence-editor

New to blender sorry if it sounds silly. In video editing I would like to copy a bunch of keyframes and paste them so that the last keyframe in the selection happens on the current frame. So like regular pasting but instead of starting at the selection the paste should end at the selection, is it possible?

EDIT: Okay I've managed to put in picture what I am looking for. In the following image, I want to select the red dots, move to frame 7460 and them cloned where the green dots are; so that the keyframes in buffer are pasted ending at the current frame. Hope this helps.

[image: example]

Comment: A screenshot might help in understanding what you are trying to do. If i get it right, you want to copy a bunch of frames and the revert the sequence, so that you have a loop, correct?

Comment: Image added, it *should* be easier to understand I hope.

Comment: Ok, you want to duplicate a selection AND you want the insertion point for the last one of the duplicated frames to be at the playhead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can try this. Switch to the Dope Sheet so you can see all your keyframes. Select the one you want to duplicate, hit SHIFT+D and the drag the mouse to where you want it to go. You can also SHIFT+select to duplicate multiple keyframes.

In your case, just move move the duplicated keyframe to the end of the timeline.

NOTE: I think the best option for you would be to type in a number instead of dragging your mouse. EG: typing "10" will move the keyframe 10 frames ahead. Subtract the target frame (the one you want to move the duplicated keyframe to) by the start frame (the frame you are duplicating it from).

[image]

Comment: That's a nice technique thank you, makes it a little easier. But not as efficient as what I had in mind.